# How to use custom html tag and style.css

Tags: c#, reactjs

I'm using a ReactHtmlParser in my react component, which reads a string with HTML code. I wonder if it is possible to use customtags in the string? Because I want to use a custom html tag to show which words should be highlighted, then adding some style settings in the css for this custom html tag.

Right now the elastic search sets the tag to  by default, but it conflicts with text where I've been using , which shouldn't be highlighted.

How can I achieve this? I tried to create a tag in the backend C# which is  but it doesn't seem to be recognized in the reactjs app.

Answer (score 1):

Please remember that whatever technology is used to create the final HTML output, it is a browser that actually renders the content to screen and HTML tags must follow standards to be interpreted correctly.  CSS classes can be applied to elements of text without creating more layout instructions.  Typically this would be done with the use of the `<span>` tag and a suitable CSS class, for example
`<p>I am some text, <span class="highlightme">I should be highlighted</span>, I should not</p>`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did as you told me to, by adding the class with highlightme.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did as you told me to, by adding the class with highlightme.
But then another problem occurred, like the style is applied on cases where I got double <em> tags in each other e.g; <em> hi, please<em class="highlightme">highlight<em>me<em/>, the hi, please part also get highlighted. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Set your style rules for em (which by default will be emphasis text) `em { /*what you want to set differently on em styles*/ }`

Comment: Then also set `em.highlightme { /*how the highlighted bit is different*/ }`